# Change the SelectedIndex in XAML to nothing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

So in XAML im trying to put the SelectedIndex on nothing but without succes. The reason I want to do this is because I have a dropdown menu but I do not want a default value when starting the application. The user should always pick a field from the start instead of having it preset for him or her.

My code:

```
<controls:ModeSelector 
        x:Name="_Menu3" x:FieldModifier="private" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Style="{StaticResource SelectorStyle}"
        Width="141" MinWidth="242" MaxWidth="292" 
        SelectedIndex="0" MaxHeight="200"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
        Height="50" IsEnabled="True" Margin="584,0,0,81" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="Height, GridBox"/>
```

The code I want to change is:`SelectedIndex="0"`, I tried removing it or changing it to null without succes, I also can't find any usefull properties in the Microsoft guides.

Comment: would `SelectedItem="{x:Null}"` work?

Comment: @JeffRSon Tried it, no succes!

Comment: Index zero is typically first item in the list; `-1` should be the correct value.  However, this is a custom control: perhaps you should share some of the code or implementation behind it.

Comment: @DanPuzey Well the code behind it is loaded from different C# classes that I did not write myself but were written by someone who was coding a proper dropdown menu for Pixelsense tables. Could you specify what you would like to see?

Comment: I'd like to see what the `SelectedIndex` is.  The answers so far assume that this is basically wrapping a standard `Combobox` or similar, but there's no guarantee that's the case.  You also said that `SelectedIndex = -1` is disabling the entire dropdown, which is non-standard.

Comment: private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedIndex = _ListBox.SelectedIndex;. So a ListBox would be the answer your looking for?